# Navbar wont update on prop change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

this is my router,
the for some reason the navbar don't update when the prop updates
but all the other components do update with the same prop
I use useState for the user but the navbar still wont change

```js
export default function CRouter() {
  const [token, setToken] = useLocalStorage('auth', '')
  const [user, setUser] = useState(false);
  const GetUser = () => {
    if (token !== "" && !user) {
      axios.post('/auth/getUser', { token }).then(res => {
        if (res.status === 200) {
          setUser(res.data);
        } else {
          setToken('');
          setUser(false);
          //mandarlo al login
        }
      })
    }
  }
  GetUser()
<Router>
      <NavBar user={user}></NavBar>
      <Switch>
        <Route
        exact
        path='/'
        render={(props)=>(
          <Home></Home>
        )}
        ></Route>
        
        <Route
          exact
          path="/forum"
          render={(props) => (
            <Forum user={user}></Forum>
          )}
        ></Route>

      
      </Switch>
    </Router>
)}
```

Comment: how do u update the prop user?

Comment: Yes, agree with @Panther. How do you update the prop user? Do you use any state? Can you add the complete code

Comment: Can you post the `NavBar` component's code?